# TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined when using ftp-deploy

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I'm trying to use [ftp-deploy](https://github.com/simonh1000/ftp-deploy) to of course deploy some files to a ftp-server. My file looks like this:

deploy.js

```
var FtpDeploy = require("ftp-deploy");
var ftpDeploy = new FtpDeploy();

var config = {
  user: "myusername",
  password: "mypassword",
  host: "myipaddress",
  port: 21,
  localRoot: __dirname + "/",
  remoteRoot: "/public_html/",
  include: ["index.html", "index.css", "assets/*"],
  deleteRoot: true
};

ftpDeploy
  .deploy(config)
  .then(res => console.log("Deployed successfully!"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

When I run `yarn deploy` I get the following error:

```
Connected to: myipaddress
Connected: Server message: --------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
You are user number 2 of 50 allowed.
Local time is now 08:43. Server port: 21.This is a private system - No anonymous login
IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Failed undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
    at canIncludePath (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/src/lib.js:53:31)
    at handleItem (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/src/lib.js:79:17)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at parseLocal (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/src/lib.js:102:23)
    at handleItem (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/src/lib.js:68:23)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Object.parseLocal (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/src/lib.js:102:23)
    at FtpDeployer.checkLocalAndUpload (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/src/ftp-deploy.js:86:27)
    at lib.checkIncludes.then.then.then.then.config (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/src/ftp-deploy.j
s:109:34)
    at tryCatcher (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/node_modules/bluebird/js/re
lease/promise.js:512:31)    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promi
se.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/prom
ise.js:614:10)    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/dean/Desktop/website/node_modules/ftp-deploy/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/
async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
✨  Done in 0.54s.
deans-imac:website dean$
```

Is this something I'm doing wrong or an error in their package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glancing at the at the source for `ftp-deploy` it looks like `exclude` might be a required config item. It appears they are calling `reduce` on it without testing it it exists. I would try adding an empty exclude: [] to the config and see if that helps.

```
var config = {
  user: "myusername",
  password: "mypassword",
  host: "myipaddress",
  port: 21,
  localRoot: __dirname + "/",
  remoteRoot: "/public_html/",
  include: ["index.html", "index.css", "assets/*"],
  exclude: [],                                     // <-- add this
  deleteRoot: true
};
```

Comment: Indeed that was the issue! Thanks so much